# How to convert this (strange formated) data ? a:5:{s:15:"nc_notification";s:1:"2";s:20:"iso_addToBook"

Tags: mysql

I tried to extract some data from a Contao Database.

I don't know this format. I search a way to convert it to JSON or something.... To make it readable.

Maybe someone know this format?...

```
a:5:{s:15:"nc_notification";
     s:1:"2";
     s:20:"iso_addToBook";
     s:1:"1";
     s:22:"checkout_skippable";
     a:1:{i:0;s:16:"shipping_address";}
```

It looks like five array-elements with a predefined string-length.

Does anyone know this format? How is it called?

Comment: https://php.net/unserialize

Answer (score 2):

That format is php serialized, something is missing in your string.The correct format should be:

`$a = ["nc_notification","2","iso_addToBook","1","checkout_skippable",["shipping_address"]];`

It returns:

`serialize($a) = "a:6:{i:0;s:15:"nc_notification";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:13:"iso_addToBook";i:3;s:1:"1";i:4;s:18:"checkout_skippable";i:5;a:1:{i:0;s:16:"shipping_address";}}"`

you can make unserialize to get back your array.

Comment: Many thanks for this hint.
I did't really know that serialize, yet.
My fav. was always JSON. A better/easier way in my eyes.